# How does ForkJoinPool#awaitQuiescence actually work?

Tags: java-8, forkjoinpool

I have next implementation of `RecursiveAction`, single purpose of this class - is to print from 0 to 9, but from different threads, if possible:

```
public class MyRecursiveAction extends RecursiveAction {
    private final int num;

    public MyRecursiveAction(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (num < 10) {
            System.out.println(num);
            new MyRecursiveAction(num + 1).fork();
        }
    }
}
```

And I thought that invoking `awaitQuiescence` will make current thread to wait until all tasks (submitted and forked) will be completed:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();
        forkJoinPool.execute(new MyRecursiveAction(0));
        System.out.println(forkJoinPool.awaitQuiescence(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ? "tasks" : "time");
    }
}
```

But I don't always get correct result, instead of printing 10 times, prints from 0 to 10 times.

But if I add `helpQuiesce` to my implementation of `RecursiveAction`:

```
public class MyRecursiveAction extends RecursiveAction {
    private final int num;

    public MyRecursiveAction(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (num < 10) {
            System.out.println(num);
            new MyRecursiveAction(num + 1).fork();
        }

        RecursiveAction.helpQuiesce();//here
    }
}
```

Everything works fine.

I want to know for what actually `awaitQuiescence` waiting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get an idea of what happens when you change the `System.out.println(num);` to `System.out.println(num + " " + Thread.currentThread());`

This may print something like:

```
0 Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main]
1 Thread[main,5,main]
tasks
2 Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main]
```

When `awaitQuiescence` detects that there are pending tasks, it helps out by stealing one and executing it directly. [Its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#awaitQuiescence(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) says:

> If called by a ForkJoinTask operating in this pool, equivalent in effect to ForkJoinTask.helpQuiesce(). Otherwise, waits and/or **attempts to assist performing tasks** until this pool isQuiescent() or the indicated timeout elapses.

<sup>Emphasis added by me</sup>

This happens here, as we can see, a task prints “main” as its executing thread. Then, the behavior of [`fork()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#fork()) is specified as:

> Arranges to asynchronously execute this task in the pool the current task is running in, if applicable, or using the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` if not `inForkJoinPool()`.

Since the `main` thread is not a worker thread of a `ForkJoinPool`, the `fork()` will submit the new task to the `commonPool()`. From that point on, the `fork()` invoked from a common pool’s worker thread will submit the next task to the common pool too. But `awaitQuiescence` invoked on the custom pool doesn’t wait for the completion of the common pool’s tasks and the JVM terminates too early.

If you’re going to say that this is a flawed API design, I wouldn’t object.

The solution is not to use `awaitQuiescence` for anything but the common pool¹. Normally, a `RecursiveAction` that splits off sub tasks should wait for their completion. Then, you can wait for the root task’s completion to wait for the completion of all associated tasks.

The second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61122549/2711488) contains an example of such a `RecursiveAction` implementation.

¹ `awaitQuiescence` is useful when you don’t have hands on the actual futures, like with a parallel stream that submits to the common pool.

Answer (score 3):

> Everything works fine.

No it does not, you got lucky that it worked when you inserted:

```
RecursiveAction.helpQuiesce();
```

To explain this let's slightly change your example a bit:

```
static class MyRecursiveAction extends RecursiveAction {

    private final int num;

    public MyRecursiveAction(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (num < 10) {
            System.out.println(num);
            new MyRecursiveAction(num + 1).fork();
        }
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();
    forkJoinPool.execute(new MyRecursiveAction(0));
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(2));
}
```

If you run this, you will notice that you get the result you expect to get. And there are two main reasons for this. First, `fork` method will execute the task in the `common pool` as the other answer already explained. And second, is that threads in the common pool are *daemon* threads. JVM is not waiting for them to finish before exiting, it exists early. So if that is the case, you might ask why it works. It does because of this line:

```
LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(2));
```

which makes the `main` thread (which is a non daemon thread) sleep for two seconds, giving enough time for the `ForkJoinPool` to execute your task.

Now let's change the code closer to your example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();
    forkJoinPool.execute(new MyRecursiveAction(0));
    System.out.println(forkJoinPool.awaitQuiescence(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ? "tasks" : "time");
}
```

specifically, you use: `forkJoinPool.awaitQuiescence(...)`, which is documented as:

> Otherwise, waits and/or attempts to assist performing tasks...

It does *not* say that it *will necessarily* wait, it says it will "wait *and/or* attempt ...", in this case it is more *or*, than *and*. As such, it will attempt to help, but still it will not wait for all the tasks to finish. Is this weird or even stupid?

When you insert `RecursiveAction.helpQuiesce();` you are eventually calling the same `awaitQuiescence` (with different arguments) under the hood - so essentially nothing changes; the fundamental problem is still there:

```
static ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();
static AtomicInteger res = new AtomicInteger(0);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    forkJoinPool.execute(new MyRecursiveAction(0));
    System.out.println(forkJoinPool.awaitQuiescence(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ? "tasks" : "time");
    System.out.println(res.get());
}

static class MyRecursiveAction extends RecursiveAction {

    private final int num;

    public MyRecursiveAction(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (num < 10_000) {
            res.incrementAndGet();
            System.out.println(num + " thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            new MyRecursiveAction(num + 1).fork();
        }

        RecursiveAction.helpQuiesce();

    }

}
```

When I run this, it never printed `10000`, showing that the insertions of that line changes nothing.

---

The usual default way to handle such things is to `fork` then `join`. And one more `join` in the caller, on the `ForkJoinTask` that you get back when calling `submit`. Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(2);
    ForkJoinTask<Void> task = forkJoinPool.submit(new MyRecursiveAction(0));
    task.join();
}

static class MyRecursiveAction extends RecursiveAction {
    private final int num;

    public MyRecursiveAction(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (num < 10) {
            System.out.println(num);
            MyRecursiveAction ac = new MyRecursiveAction(num + 1);
            ac.fork();
            ac.join();
        }
    }
}
```